# How can I access the 'results' object that is returned when running a Parse query?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm running a Parse query on all user objects (`usersQuery`), then querying for all `MCI_Results` objects that fulfill certain criteria (`MCI_Results_Query`).

Based on how many `MCI_Results` objects fulfill the criteria, I'm sending two different possible push notifications containing the `searchTerm` property of the that object as you can see below. When I attempt to run this code, it gives me an error stating:

> Cannot read property 'searchTerm' of undefined

I'm assuming this is because `results[0]` itself is undefined, and that that's not the correct way to access the first object in results. How can I properly access it?

**Code:**

```
// For each user in the DB...       
    return usersQuery.each(function(user) {
            // find all MCI_Results items with a newMatch of "YES" and a priority level of "High"
            var MCI_Results = Parse.Object.extend("MCI_Results");
            var MCI_Results_Query = new Parse.Query(MCI_Results);

            MCI_Results_Query.equalTo('parent', user);
            MCI_Results_Query.contains('newMatch', 'YES');
            MCI_Results_Query.contains('itemPriority', 'High');
            MCI_Results_Query.find()
                .then(function(result) {
                    // Send a notification with the items name in it.
                    //
                    console.log('the MCI_Results_Query result is as follows:' + result);

                    // If >1 high priority items, say "New matches for _____ and X more items"
                    if (result.length > 1) {
                        var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                        pushQuery.containsAll("channels", [user.id, "highPush"]);

                        Parse.Push.send({
                            where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
                            data: {
                                alert: "New matches found for" + result[0].searchTerm + "and" + result.length-1 + "more items!"
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    // If 1 high priority item, say "New matches for _____!"
                    else if (result.length = 1) {
                        var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                        pushQuery.containsAll("channels", [user.id, "highPush"]);

                        Parse.Push.send({
                            where: pushQuery,
                            data: {
                                alert: "New matches found for" + result[0].searchTerm + "!"
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // If no high priority items, don't send any push notification.
                        console.log('No high priority items fo u');
                    }

                });

        });
```

Comment: What does the `console.log` show?

Comment: It just says 'the MCI_Results_Query result is as follows:', which made me think result was empty, but when i tried result.length instead, it was giving lengths for every user.

Comment: Instead of using console.log, use the Javascript debugger and examine the variable directly.

Comment: @Barmar Parse doesn't offer a tool for stepping through cloud code as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Parse.com. I thought this code was running in the client, so you should be able to use its Javascript debugger.